# reactjs change state of select with out clicking on it

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

I have the following select component in my react program:

```
<select>
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to be able to change which option is selected when some event takes place, say pressing a button, in addition to being able to change which option is selected by interacting with the drop down menu. How can I do this? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
<select>
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
</select>
<button/> // when this button is pressed I want
          // the selected option to change to option1
          // regardless of the selects current state
```

Thanks

Please note: I am not asking how to change the default state of the select, I want to be able to change it at run time by pressing a button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a `state` variable to control the selected value and then update that `state` variable onClick of a button.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedOption: ""
        };
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value});
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({selectedOption: "foo"});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <select value={this.state.selectedOption} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <option value="">Default</option>
                    <option value="foo">Foo</option>
                    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
                </select>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```